# Google Maps API loads from html file, but not on local host

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps-api-3, localhost

I am trying to connect to the Google Maps API from a localhost through an AngularJS application but the map does not appear and the map request does not reach google. The javascript file is being found by the html, and `test1` is being outputted in the console, but `initMap` is not being called and `test2` is not outputted. I expect that it is failing because a https connection is not being made to Google.

When I open the html file in a browser, the map loads fine but when I run it on my localhost, nothing comes up.

Here is my html code:

```
<script src="client/services/maps.client.services.map.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{API_KEY}}&callback=initMap"></script>
```

and javascript (map.js):

```
console.log('test1');
function initMap() {
  console.log('test2');

  //Markers
  var markers = [
      ['Cardiff', 51.4539, -3.1694, 'city/cardiff'],
      ['Swansea', 51.6148, -3.92927895, 'city/swansea']
  ];

  // Initialise map
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 10,
    center: {lat: 51.4539, lng: -3.1694}
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for( i = 0; i < markers.length; i++ ) {
    // Plot pin for each place
    var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
    bounds.extend(position);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: position,
      map: map,
      title: markers[i][0]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        window.location.href = markers[i][3];
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }

  // Zoom so all pins are in view
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
```

Does anyone understand why the `initMap` function is not being called?

Comment: you can't add angular variables to the script src

Comment: ok @sachilaranawaka, how can I get this function to run to initiate the map?

Comment: just call the function right after the first console

Comment: @sachilaranawaka That calls the function, but when `var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map')` is called, it errors with Google is not defined.. any ideas? Thanks for your help

Comment: because the script tag is not working. add a valid token to the script and try it

Comment: @sachilaranawaka The {{API_KEY}} is just a placeholder, the token in there is correct

Comment: check the answer

Answer (score 0):

change the order of the script tags

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{API_KEY}}&callback=initMap"></script>
<script src="client/services/maps.client.services.map.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've already tried that and it doesn't work. The error I get is: maps.client.scripts.map.js:24 Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
    at initMap (maps.client.scripts.map.js:24)
    at maps.client.scripts.map.js:2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704063/google-map-error-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-yeoman