# Angular - Google maps API - Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined - only sometimes?

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript

I've seen this question asked 100 times, but none of the answers seem to work. I'm trying to declare a class like this:

```
class Popup extends google.maps.OverlayView {
  // Classy stuff
}
```

but I always get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined`

Thing is, Google Maps works everywhere else in my code, but not when I declare this class. Also, I'm declaring it just after a class like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.scss',]
})
export class MapComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  map: google.maps.Map; <-- No problem with google namespace here
  // Map stuff
}

class Popup extends google.maps.OverlayView { <-- Problem is with this google namespace
  // Classy stuff
}
```

and I refresh the page and sometimes it loads, and other times crashes and gives me that error.

I'm loading in my index.html like this:

```
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=myKey&libraries=places"></script>
```

and it's always worked (I use google maps all through this project, and have yet to have an issue with any other google namespace. Just when I try to create that class)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review this [Angular Google Map API Documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/GoogleMapApi) before lurking around and looking for a work-around.

Feel free to review [these answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24704063/google-map-error-uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-yeoman) as they appear to address the same issue you are having.

It could be that: 1) Your scripts are not loading properly so the global Google.Maps is not recognized.  or... 2) `angular-google-maps` is processing directives before Google Maps SDK is fully ready.

Comment: Looks like that may be for AngularJs. Would be good though if there was a decent one for Angular, but I've never found anything I can customize well enough. I do think you're right about things not loading in the right order...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because the overlay is not loaded yet, but the map is. If you look at the order in which scripts load, `map` is loaded before `overlay`; that's probably why you have the problem with `overlay` but not `map`. But you could still have problem with `map` I think, depending on network speed.

You should try without loading your script with `async` and `defer` to make sure that the library is loaded synchronously before you try to use it

Even Google suggest to load their script synchronously when trying to subclass the API classes

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple

> In effect, this will subclass the overlay class therefore
>         it's simpler to load the API synchronously